# String Length Issue

Tags: php

I have four string length statements I am trying to validate,but only two are working.

```
$name = "mike";
$age = "54";
$city = "Chicago";
$building = "Madadnock";
$lengthOfString1 = strlen ( $name );
echo "String length of 'name' " . $lengthOfString1  . "</br>";

$lengthOfString2 = strlen ( $age );
echo "String length of 'age' " . $lengthOfString2  . "</br>";
$lengthOfString3 = strlen ( $city );
echo "String length of 'city' " . $lengthOfstring3  . "</br>";

$lengthOfString4 = strlen ( $building );
echo "String length of 'building' " . $lengthOfstring4  . "</br>";
```

The top two are the only ones that work. Any help would be great!

Comment: add more details about how those last two statements not working

Comment: This question should have been closed as a duplicate with [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, and “Notice: Undefined offset”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Sidenote: `</br>` isn't a valid markup tag; `<br/>` is.

Answer (score 3):

variables in PHP are case sensitive

```
$lengthOfString4 vs $lengthOfstring4
         ^                   ^
```

Comment: same goes for `$lengthOfstring3`

Comment: @Fred-ii- great observation fred :)

Comment: I worked in a typesetting/graphics-related environment for a long time ;-) One picks up on those after a while.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in variable names. The variable names in PHP are case-sensitive.

```
$lengthOfString3 = strlen ( $city );
echo "String length of 'city' " . $lengthOfString3  . "</br>";

$lengthOfString4 = strlen ( $building );
echo "String length of 'building' " . $lengthOfString4  . "</br>";
```

Fixed it.